# Last Button Spread on entire GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I created a Java Class that contains a tiny calculator to perform addition and multiplication functionality having 3 text fields for input output and some labels with buttons. The problem is that, when I placed all items to their x,y coordinates and set their width and heights, the last button spreads on entire screen at background of GUI window. Here is the code, please tell me the issue. thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SmallCalcApp implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel firstOperand, secondOperand, answer; 
    JTextField op1, op2, ans;
    JButton plus, mul;

    public SmallCalcApp(){
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        Container con = frame.getContentPane();


        //initialization of objects
        plus = new JButton("+");
        mul = new JButton("*");
        op1 = new JTextField();
        op2 = new JTextField();
        ans = new JTextField();
        firstOperand = new JLabel("First Number: ");
        secondOperand = new JLabel("Second Number: ");
        answer = new JLabel("Calculated Result: ");


        firstOperand.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 20);
        op1.setBounds(200, 0, 150, 20);
        secondOperand.setBounds(0, 200, 150, 20);
        op2.setBounds(200, 200, 150, 20);
        answer.setBounds(0, 300, 150, 20);
        ans.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 20);
        plus.setBounds(0, 400, 50, 50);
        mul.setBounds(200, 400, 50, 50);




        con.add(firstOperand);
        con.add(op1);
        con.add(secondOperand); 
        con.add(op2);   
        con.add(answer);    
        con.add(ans);
        con.add(plus);
        con.add(mul);



        plus.addActionListener(this);
        mul.addActionListener(this);



        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String oper, result;
            int num1, num2, res;



            if(event.getSource() == plus){
                oper = op1.getText();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                oper = op2.getText();
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                res = num1 + num2;
                result = res + "";

                ans.setText(result);
            }

            if(event.getSource() == mul){
                oper = op1.getText();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                oper = op2.getText();
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);

                res = num1 * num2;
                result = res + "";

                ans.setText(result);
            }
        } 


    public static void main(String[] args){
        SmallCalcApp sc = new SmallCalcApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty classical case-study in why you shouldn't use Absolute Positioning. The first paragraph in the [Absolute Positioning Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) says "*Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs.*"

Comment: i tried to use layout managers, they spread everything around.

Comment: Which is why you need to know the correct type to use. I'm doing a bit of testing to make sure my solution will work for you, but in the meantime, look at [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which is often a very natural idiom for GUIs with fixed-size components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should avoid Absolute Positioning. If you *do* need to expressly specify pixel coordinates for objects, prefer a layout manager like [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which at least gives you direct control over grid size and spacing.

For your purposes, I think it makes the most sense to build a 9x9 grid, 50 pixels each, and then specify each of your objects to take up several of these boxes each.

So in your `initGUI` method, we'll first set the layout:

```
GridBagLayout layout;
public void initGUI() {
    /*...*/
    con.setLayout(layout = new GridBagLayout());
    layout.columnWidths = new int[9];
    Arrays.fill(layout.columnWidths, 50);
    layout.rowHeights = new int[9];
    Arrays.fill(layout.rowHeights, 50);
```

Then, after this, we'll define constraints for each of the objects being displayed in your app. This gets a little verbose, but a lot of it is boilerplate code.

```
//Label will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 0,0, and we'll add 30 pixels of padding below it.
GridBagConstraints firstOperandConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        0,0,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Text field will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 200(50*4),0, and have 30 pixels of padding below it
GridBagConstraints op1Constraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        4,0,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Label will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 0,200 (50*4), and we'll add 30 pixels of padding below it.
GridBagConstraints secondOperandConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        0,4,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Field will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 200,200 (50*4), and we'll add 30 pixels of padding below it.
GridBagConstraints op2Constraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        4,4,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Label will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 0,300 (50*6), and we'll add 30 pixels of padding below it.
GridBagConstraints answerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        0,6,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Label will be 150 (50*3) pixels wide, start at 300,300 (50*6), and we'll add 30 pixels of padding below it.
GridBagConstraints ansConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        6,6,
        3,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Button will be 50 pixels wide/tall, start at 0,400 (50*8), and it won't have any padding
GridBagConstraints plusConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        0,8,
        1,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
        0, 0
        );
//Button will be 50 pixels wide/tall, start at 200,400 (50*4/50*8), and it won't have any padding
GridBagConstraints mulConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(
        4,8,
        1,1,
        1,1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
        0, 0
        );
```

We'll then specify each of these constraints when adding the buttons/labels/fields:

```
con.add(firstOperand, firstOperandConstraints);
con.add(op1, op1Constraints);
con.add(secondOperand, secondOperandConstraints); 
con.add(op2, op2Constraints);   
con.add(answer, answerConstraints);    
con.add(ans, ansConstraints);
con.add(plus, plusConstraints);
con.add(mul, mulConstraints);
```

And finally, we'll make the frame unresizable to ensure that things don't move around:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setResizable(false);
```

This results in an app that looks like this:

[image: App]

With grid lines added (manually by hand, so they're a little uneven), we can see how it divided up the screen:

[image: App with Grid Lines]

Depending on your requirements, you may need to "beautify" this app by moving components around or resizing things. A few things to consider:

- You can get any arbitrary positioning you need by combining grid positions and Insets. A box occupying `[230,170]-[290,320]` could be easily represented by having the object start at position 4,3, giving it width/height values of 2,4, and specifying Insets of `(20, 30, 30, 10)`.
- If you want the frame to be resizable without altering the positions/sizes of the components, you'll need to bundle these into their own panel and add that panel to the root content pane.

Below is an example that allows the frame itself to be resized without moving the buttons/fields/labels around, or being resized too small to show those components:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setLayout(layout = new GridBagLayout());
layout.columnWidths = new int[9];
Arrays.fill(layout.columnWidths, 50);
layout.rowHeights = new int[9];
Arrays.fill(layout.rowHeights, 50);

panel.add(firstOperand, firstOperandConstraints);
panel.add(op1, op1Constraints);
panel.add(secondOperand, secondOperandConstraints); 
panel.add(op2, op2Constraints);   
panel.add(answer, answerConstraints);    
panel.add(ans, ansConstraints);
panel.add(plus, plusConstraints);
panel.add(mul, mulConstraints);

GridBagLayout rootLayout = new GridBagLayout();
rootLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{450};
rootLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{450};
con.setLayout(rootLayout);
con.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setMinimumSize(null); //To make sure the pack() directive doesn't result in a frame larger than the components
frame.pack();
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I am very thankful to you. I googled so many topics about GridBagLayout but unable to understand them, all were difficult. But your this comment taught me it very easily. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any swing application Layout is must. So you have to set "setLayout" for any container. Set layout 'null' or any layout you want. if you don't set layout every component will occupy whole container. For Calculater type application "GridLayout" is suitable. For quick solution you can use the following line.

```
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(null);
```